# Druid always tries to resolve Kafka broker to localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I have a Kafka instance running on another machine in my local network which I'm trying to ingest into Druid. My ingestion spec looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "ioConfig": {
    "type": "kafka",
    "consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "192.168.0.102:9092"
    },
    "topic": "metrics"
  },
  "tuningConfig": {
    "type": "kafka"
  },
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "metrics",
    "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      "segmentGranularity": "HOUR",
      "queryGranularity": "HOUR"
    },
    "parser": {
      "parseSpec": {
        "format": "json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the overlord returns me this error even though I'm not trying to connect to localhost: `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=kafka-supervisor-bebmfiod] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

When I put something like google.com:9092 it gives an error that no topic metadata could be found.

The IP is resolvable on Druid machine (can confirm via ping). Druid version is `0.16.0`.

I've been struggling with this error for some days. I tried both Druid Docker version and native one (initially thought it could be some connectivity issue related to docker).

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: forgot to mention I can confirm Kafka is working properly while testing via `kafka-console-consumer` and kafka-console-producer`.

Edit:

First tab image:

[image]

Connect tab:

[image]

Comment: Do you send this spec to API or through UI? If through UI - can you see data in the preview window(first tab of "Load Data" wizard)?

Comment: Through the UI. I've just included those printscreens.

Comment: Kafka default advertised.listeners is set to localhost:9092

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Thank you a lot cricket_007!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User cricket_007 pointed out that `advertised.listeners` was not properly set up under Kafka settings (server.properties file). Setting it to PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.102:9092 surely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `server.properties` file (under `{PATH_TO_KAFKA}/config`), the default setting of `advertised.listeners` is:

```
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
```

As OneCricketeer said, setting it to:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{ip}:9092
```

Where `ip` is your computer IP address and problem will be solved.